# Does minimum balance for rent exempt change over time

Tags: transactions, wallet, rent

I am building a wallet where I have multiple accounts. I would like to know what the rent exempt line is at all times. So that when transfers are being made, they don't end up failing because they go below the rent exempt line.

I found the "getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption", and none of the accounts are programs, so the data size is 0 for all of them.

The only thing I don't know is how often does this change, is it worth checking this regularly, even thought the data size for the accounts is 0?

I am new to SOL so if I misunderstood anything please let me know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as it said here : https://docs.solana.com/developing/intro/rent, currently the rent rate is static, however it may change later.